# In Microsoft Word, is there a way to conditionally format the cell properties of a MS Word Table (like in Microsoft Excel)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, styles

**Background:** So, in Micrsoft Excel, you may colorize or affect the design/style of a cell via the "Conditional Formatting" feature that is present in the standard/plain vanilla version of Microsoft Excel (i.e., there is no need for an add-on or to use VB script). My question here is whether or not we can do that with Microsoft Word as of February 2024.

[image]

Comment: Not nearly as simply or easily. You do not have conditional formatting, you have conditional content using an IF field. That is, you would repeat the content and format it the way you want to meet each condition. Even then, it is not automatic; something needs to trigger updating the IF fields. Simpler is to insert an Excel part into the Word document.

Answer (score 0):

Word does not have a simple method for Conditional Formatting.
You will need to use VBA for that.

See the post
[Conditional Formatting in a table on MS Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/conditional-formatting-in-a-table-on-ms-word/6f6cba05-d765-4f83-bba7-647eef2daf9f)
which shows a Coronavirus risk-assessment table.

This is an excerpt from the VBA macro that is proposed in the post:

```
Select Case Val(crange.Text) 
    Case 1 To 4 
        crange.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(153, 204, 0)
```

You will need to define a VBA macro that will be triggered upon
any change in the document and will test if these fields were changed
and will set their background color accordingly.

Here are some references that can get you started:

- [Walkthrough: Call code from VBA in a Visual Basic project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-from-vba-in-a-visual-basic-project?view=vs-2022)
- [Excel VBA: Power Tips to Revolutionize Your Data Analysis](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/excel-tutorial/excel-vba)

Comment: Or create the table in Excel, and insert an exported PDF or image into word. That has the disadvantage of not being selectable or editable text, whereas VBA is truly editable and updates with changes -- but VBA may not be allowed in some cases.